# Trying to create a Rock Paper Scissors game

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a rock paper scissors game to work. I am doing it in `JavaScript` and it's for a school assignment. When I run the game and try to click one of the rock paper or scissors images, it shows in the debug console that it was clicked. But the actions I want it to do are not performed. What should I do?

```
// Numbers are being assigned to the variables of the computer and the computer's choice.

var compChoice1 = randomNumber(0, 1);
var compChoice2 = randomNumber(0, 1);
var compChoice3 = randomNumber(0, 1);

var compChoice = computer;

if (compChoice1 <= 0.3) {
  compChoice1 = "scissorsImage";
}

if (compChoice2 >= 0.6) {
  compChoice2 = "rockImage";
}

if (compChoice3 == (0.4 || 0.5)) {
  compChoice = "paperImage";
}

// Values are being assigned to the variables of the user's choice. 
var scissorsChoice = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3];
var rockChoice = [0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1];
var paperChoice = [0.4, 0.5];

// If the rock is clicked, the user will be taken to tie, lose, or win screen depending on the 
// computer's choice.
onEvent("rockImage", "click", function( ) {
  if (rockChoice == "scissorsChoice") {
    setScreen("youWin");
  } else {
    if (rockChoice == "rockChoice") {
      setScreen("tieScreen");
      onEvent("backToStart", "click", function( ) {
        setScreen("welcomeScreen");
      });
    }
  }
  if (rockChoice == "paperChoice") {
    setScreen("youLose");
    onEvent("startOver2", "click", function( ) {
      setScreen("welcomeScreen");
    });
  }
});

// If the paper is clicked, the user will be taken to tie, lose, or win screen depending on the 
// computer's choice.
onEvent("paperImage", "click", function( ) {
  if (paperChoice == "scissorsChoice") {
    setScreen("youLose");
  } else {
    if (paperChoice == "rockChoice") {
      setScreen("youWin");
    }
  }
  if (paperChoice == "paperChoice") {
    setScreen("tieScreen");
  }
});

// If the scissors are clicked, the user will be taken to tie, lose, or win screen depending on the 
// computer's choice.
onEvent("scissorsImage", "click", function( ) {
  if (scissorsChoice == "scissorsChoice") {
    setScreen("tieScreen");
  } else {
    if (scissorsChoice == "rockChoice") {
      setScreen("youLose");
    }
  }
  if (scissorsChoice == "paperChoice") {
    setScreen("youWin");
  }
});
```

Comment: _"But the actions I want it to do are not performed. What should I do"_. Please clarify what is happening wrong and that you expect.

Comment: You use the function `setScreen` again and again and I see no implementation of such a function. What does it do Or can you share the code of this function?

Comment: Improved wording

Comment: @NorbertBartko I have to do it in the website code.org since its a school assignment and we are required to do it in there. [link](https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/mbgzlGAD7MoUOZ41vs--xOZ7VLztrAS2-EMHLeyS1Ig)